# Most elegant and efficient way to remove disallowed characters from a C++ string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, text

I am using C++11 and am wondering what is the most elegant to process an existing C++ string such that it only contains these valid characters below.  Efficiency is also a concern, but looking for elegance foremost.

"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-";

Thank you,
Virgil.

Comment: Hint: there's an algorithm for it.

Comment: Sounds like something `while(i = s.find_first_not_of(...) != npos) s.erase(i)` would do.

Comment: For long strings with possibly many matches, the most efficient solution will almost certainly not be the most elegant one. It will likely be copying non-matching characters to a new string and swapping strings at the end, as erasing characters will cause many calls to `memmove` (or its equivalent).

Comment: @Damon Any solution that has more than one call to `erase` fails at both elegance and efficiency.

Comment: @Damon `std::copy_if` followed by `swap` should be fast any the code probably isn't hairy.

Answer (score 10):

Here's my go:

```
void removeDisallowed(std::string& in) {
    static const std::string allowed = "01234...";
    in.erase(
        std::remove_if(in.begin(), in.end(), [&](const char c) {
            return allowed.find(c) == std::string::npos;
        }),
        in.end());
}
```

If you want to make it more efficient, you could make a set:

```
std::unordered_set<char> allowedSet(allowed.begin(), allowed.end());
```

And change the check to:

```
return !allowedSet.count(c);
```

[Update] Based on a lot of good comments and answers, I'd suggest just writing a:

```
template <typename F>
void erase_if(std::string& in, F func) {
    in.erase(std::remove_if(in.begin(), in.end(), func));
}
```

And then actually trying to run it with all the various proposed `func`s and see which one works best for your use-case. This won't work with Dietmar's answer, so you'll have to try that one separately, but they're probably all worth a shot.

Comment: Quite nice :-)  I'll give it a couple of hours to see what other answers come in before I accept :)

Comment: The predicate `(ìsalnum(c) || c == '_' || c == '-')` would probably be faster, but it's less general. (OTOH, it's more locale-aware.)

Comment: `find` -> `binary_search` also faster if `allowed` is sorted.

Comment: @pepper_chico: did you measure or are you speculating? I haven't measured this specific set up but based on other similar measurements it isn't a priori clear which of these two options is faster.

Comment: @DietmarKühl speculating.

Comment: So basically, some version of `in.erase(std::remove_if(in.begin(), in.end(), func));` is likely the best answer. Whether `func` is a `find`, `binary_search`, `count`, or an array lookup in a table is unknowable without testing.

Comment: @pepper_chico: The my response for results from a fairly simple benchmark (which indicates that the regex approach is elegant but not that fast).

Comment: @DietmarKühl Nice, I can't drawn for sure from names you have employed which method is which, I believe hash is about unordered_set and ctype is the lookup_table?

Comment: @pepper_chico: correct. I also added a version using a specific table filled with the characters to remove.

Comment: Note that using `switch`/`case` may be much faster than `unordered_set<char>`, which may be even slower than using something like `boost::replace_all`. I tried to remove all `{ '\r', '\n', '\t', ' ' }` in a file of around 30 MB. Using `fileString.erase(remove_if(fileString.begin(), fileString.end(), [&](const char c) { switch (c) { case '\r': case '\n': case '\t': case ' ': return true; default: return false; } }), fileString.end());` took **142.23 ms**, using `unordered_set<char>` as a blacklist took **588.99 ms**, and using four `boost::replace_all(...)` calls took **257.22 ms**.

Answer (score 7):

It seems the most *elegant* approach would be the use of a regular expression (note the enclosing square brackets):

```
std::regex const filter("[^0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-]");
str = std::regex_replace(str, filter, "");
```

Following the comments about performance I cooked up a quick benchmark which is checked in on [github](https://github.com/dietmarkuehl/cputube/blob/master/cpu/test/replace.cpp). It compares some of the suggestions. Here is a summary of the result run on a MacOS notebook with recent versions of [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) using high optimization options. The numbers shown are the times taken in μs to process a lengthy text document:

```
benchmark                         gcc      clang
regex (build                     186131    552697
regex (prebuild)                 177959    566353
use_remove_if_str_find            44802     40644
use_remove_if_find                88377    123237
use_remove_if_binary_search       54091     64065
use_remove_if_ctype               13818     12901
use_remove_if_hash                81341     58582
use_remove_if_table                9033     10203
```

The first two benchmarks use the regex approach posted above while the others use [Barry's `std::remove_if()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26808603/1120273) using different approaches to implement the predicate inside the lambda. To clarify the names an outline of what is done (inside a lambda, combined with `erase()` as needed, etc):

1. regex (build): `text = std::regex_replace(text, std::regex("[^" + allowed + "]"), "")`
2. regex (prebuild): `text = std::regex_replace(text, filter, "")` (building the regex is outside the timing)
3. remove_if str find: `std::remove_if(... a.find(c))`
4. remove_if find: `std::remove_if(... std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), c) == a.end())`
5. remove_if binary_search: `std::remove_if(... std::binary_search(a.begin(), a.end(), c))`
6. remove_if ctype: `std::remove_if(... isalnum(c) || c == '-' || c == '_')`
7. remove_if hash: `std::remove_if(... unordered_set.count(c))`
8. remove_if table: `std::remove_if(... table[c])`

For details have a look at the [source](https://github.com/dietmarkuehl/cputube/blob/master/cpu/test/replace.cpp).

Comment: It looks like this operates in the wrong direction. Your regex seemingly replaces all of the allowed characters!

Comment: @Novelocrat Haha I +1ed before I even noticed that :) I liked the elegance so much, I apparently didn't mind the anti-correctness...

Comment: @Barry, just beware with regexes when you're looking for speed. Never forget to profile ;-)

Comment: @pepper_chico: building the filter ahead of time could actually yield a reasonably decent approach (changing the code to move the regex construction into the opportune location). It may be worth measuring different approaches, though.

Comment: Btw, proof that big-oh notation is never sufficient for performance analysis. Three `O(1)` functions in there with a 10x time gap, and one of the `O(N)` ones is faster than a `O(lg N)` one is faster than a `O(1)` one. That's pretty cool.

Comment: @Barry: well, the asymptotic complexity is actually still relevant: with bigger data sets the situation rapidly changes. I haven't measured how many characters would be needed to change the order. ... and given that the input size is actually limited, the computational complexity of all of these operations happens to be bounded by a constant.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I didn't say it was irrelevant, just that it's insufficient.

Comment: wouldn't the regex be easier to read if you just did: "[^\\w-]" or even "[^0-9a-zA-Z_-]"

Answer (score 6):

This may be simplistic but I would consider using a constant time lookup table that fits in a few cache lines.

```
void remove_disallowed(std::string &str)
{
    static const char disallowed[] = {
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    };
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [&](char c) {
        return disallowed[static_cast<unsigned char>(c)];
    }), str.end());
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice one. What about trying out [binary literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Binary_literals) =)

Comment: @pepper_chico: You can substitute your favorite technique to generate the lookup table. You could even pass the table as a parameter to customize the behavior at runtime.

Comment: Yeah indeed, would be nice to have `disallowed` as parameter and a function to produce a mapping from a string of chars to lookup.

Comment: @pepper_chico: [Something like this demo code at ideone.com?](http://ideone.com/y8EgC1)

Comment: I have drawn from your answer already. I believe it's better since it doesn't touch pointers and `memset`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>

void keep_chars_in_set(std::string &s, const std::unordered_set<char> &chars) {
    s.erase(
        std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [&chars](const char c) {
            return !chars.count(c);
        }),
        s.end());
}

void keep_sorted_chars(std::string &s, const std::string &sorted_chars) {
    s.erase(
        std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [&sorted_chars](const char c) {
            return !std::binary_search(sorted_chars.begin(), sorted_chars.end(), c);
        }),
        s.end());
}

using lookup_table = std::array<bool, std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()>;

lookup_table make_lookup_table(const std::string &s) {
    lookup_table t = {};
    for (auto c : s) {
        t[static_cast<size_t>(c)] = true;
    }
    return t;
}

void keep_chars_in_lookup_table(std::string &s, const lookup_table &table) {
    s.erase(
        std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [&table](const char c) {
            return !table[static_cast<size_t>(c)];
        }),
        s.end());
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    string s1 = "abcdefxabc";
    string s2 = "abcdefyabc";
    string s3 = "abcdefzabc";

    const unordered_set<char> set_of_chars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
    keep_chars_in_set(s1, set_of_chars);
    cout << s1 << endl;

    keep_sorted_chars(s2, "abcdef");
    cout << s2 << endl;

    const lookup_table &char_lookup_table = make_lookup_table("abcdef");
    keep_chars_in_lookup_table(s3, char_lookup_table);
    cout << s3 << endl;
}
```

Notes:

- `binary_search` should be faster than `find`: O(lg N) vs O(N), full solutions being O(M lg N) vs O(M * N).
- `unordered_set` is not a contiguous data structure, so, even if search is O(1) (with full solution (O(M))), it may not be cache friendly, and hence you should profile.
- lookup table method should be the faster one, it's both cache friendly and with less complexity (O(M)).
- This draws from several other answers.

Comment: For consistency with the question, you might want to flip the implementation from taking what chars to *remove* to take what chars to *keep*.

Comment: @Barry True. I was confused by this reply, has nothing to do with the question.